# iOS Build Error "Typedef redefinition with different types ('NSUInteger' (aka 'unsigned long') vs 'enum MTLPixelFormat')"

Tags: ios, xcode

I am new to iOS, I just tried to build my Unity game for iOS and it gives me these errors. [See image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GtyZ0.png) Can someone help? Please

1. Typedef redefinition with different types ('NSUInteger' (aka 'unsigned long') vs 'enum MTLPixelFormat')
2. Redefinition of enumerator 'MTLPixelFormatBGRA8Unorm'
3. Redefinition of enumerator 'MTLPixelFormatBGRA8Unorm_sRGB'

Comment: Post your code. It sounds like you're using "Objective-C++" (mixed Objective-C and C++ syntax)

Comment: I fixed it by just commenting the code, but now having new errors. Please see this if you can help.

[link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46864491/unidentified-symbol-for-architecture-arm64-xcode-9)

Answer (score 0):

This error is raised as your project is using Metal.framework and iOS simulator does not support metalframework. If you run your project on iphone device it will run fine.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this problem simply comment out the offending lines.

```
//typedef NSUInteger MTLPixelFormat;
//enum
//{
//    MTLPixelFormatBGRA8Unorm,
//    MTLPixelFormatBGRA8Unorm_sRGB,
//};
```

([Source](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/148875/typedef-redefinition-error-when-running-unity-ios-project-in-xcode-9-simulator))