# Unidentified symbol for architecture arm64, Xcode 9

Tags: ios, xcode, linker, match

I made a game using Unity3D, now when I am building it in Xcode, I am getting Apple Mach-o linker Errors.

It says "Unidentified symbol for architecture arm64"

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_addProgressionEvent", referenced from:
      _GA_Wrapper_addProgressionEvent_m80528921 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.o
     (maybe you meant: _GA_Wrapper_addProgressionEvent_m80528921, _GA_Wrapper_addProgressionEventWithScore_m101319912 )
  "_addBusinessEventAndAutoFetchReceipt", referenced from:
      _GA_Wrapper_addBusinessEventAndAutoFetchReceipt_m977199840 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.o
     (maybe you meant: _GA_Wrapper_addBusinessEventAndAutoFetchReceipt_m977199840)
  "_addBusinessEvent", referenced from:
      _GA_Wrapper_addBusinessEvent_m893710814 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.o
     (maybe you meant: _GA_Wrapper_addBusinessEvent_m893710814, _GA_Wrapper_addBusinessEventAndAutoFetchReceipt_m977199840 )
  "_gameAnalyticsEndSession", referenced from:
      _GA_Wrapper_EndSession_m4052399451 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.o
      _GA_Wrapper_gameAnalyticsEndSession_m3880671327 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.o
     (maybe you meant: _GA_Wrapper_gameAnalyticsEndSession_m3880671327)
  "_configureUserId", referenced from:
      _GameAnalytics_SetCustomId_m1003311179 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.o
      _GA_Wrapper_SetCustomUserId_m597501021 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.o
      _GA_Wrapper_configureUserId_m3738958582 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.o
     (maybe you meant: _GA_Wrapper_configureUserId_m3738958582)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_UNNotificationAttachment", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libOneSignal.a(OneSignalHelper.o)
  "_setFacebookId", referenced from:
      _GA_Setup_SetFacebookId_m721453015 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.o
      _GA_Wrapper_SetFacebookId_m3845418779 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.o
      _GameAnalytics_SetFacebookId_m1032597082 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.o
      _GA_Wrapper_setFacebookId_m4137119355 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.o
     (maybe you meant: _GA_Wrapper_setFacebookId_m4137119355)
  "_configureSdkGameEngineVersion", referenced from:
      _GameAnalytics_Initialize_m4261803041 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.o
      _GA_Wrapper_SetUnitySdkVersion_m2287164767 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.o
      _GA_Wrapper_configureSdkGameEngineVersion_m3051309580 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.o
     (maybe you meant: _GA_Wrapper_configureSdkGameEngineVersion_m3051309580)
  "_configureGameEngineVersion", referenced from:
      _GameAnalytics_Initialize_m4261803041 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.o
      _GA_Wrapper_SetUnityEngineVersion_m3940550889 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.o
      _GA_Wrapper_configureGameEngineVersion_m314945090 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.o
     (maybe you meant: _GA_Wrapper_configureGameEngineVersion_m314945090)
  "_addProgressionEventWithScore", referenced from:
      _GA_Wrapper_addProgressionEventWithScore_m101319912 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.o
     (maybe you meant: _GA_Wrapper_addProgressionEventWithScore_m101319912)
  "_showSocialSharing", referenced from:
      _NativeShare_showSocialSharing_m407316830 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
     (maybe you meant: _NativeShare_showSocialSharing_m407316830)
  "_setManualSessionHandling", referenced from:
      _GameAnalytics_Initialize_m4261803041 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.o
      _GameAnalytics_SetEnabledManualSessionHandling_m3440684272 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.o
      _GA_Wrapper_SetEnabledManualSessionHandling_m763084429 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.o
      _GA_Wrapper_setManualSessionHandling_m534115778 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.o
     (maybe you meant: _GA_Wrapper_setManualSessionHandling_m534115778)
  "_setBirthYear", referenced from:
      _GA_Setup_SetBirthYear_m3047716971 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.o
      _GA_Wrapper_SetBirthYear_m142480455 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.o
      _GameAnalytics_SetBirthYear_m2354233992 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.o
      _GA_Wrapper_setBirthYear_m1760892199 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.o
     (maybe you meant: _GA_Wrapper_setBirthYear_m1760892199)
  "_addDesignEventWithValue", referenced from:
      _GA_Design_CreateNewEvent_m923612557 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.o
      _GA_Wrapper_AddDesignEvent_m1415925800 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.o
      _GA_Wrapper_addDesignEventWithValue_m1908537775 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.o
     (maybe you meant: _GA_Wrapper_addDesignEventWithValue_m1908537775)
  "_setGender", referenced from:
      _GA_Setup_SetGender_m2773802828 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.o
      _GA_Wrapper_SetGender_m3892245433 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.o
      _GA_Wrapper_setGender_m857923737 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.o
     (maybe you meant: _GA_Wrapper_setGender_m857923737)
  "_configureAvailableResourceItemTypes", referenced from:
      _GA_Setup_SetAvailableResourceItemTypes_m214260229 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.o
      _GA_Wrapper_SetAvailableResourceItemTypes_m3737669819 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.o
      _GA_Wrapper_configureAvailableResourceItemTypes_m2032723269 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.o
     (maybe you meant: _GA_Wrapper_configureAvailableResourceItemTypes_m2032723269)
  "_configureAvailableCustomDimensions02", referenced from:
      _GA_Setup_SetAvailableCustomDimensions02_m785816759 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.o
      _GA_Wrapper_SetAvailableCustomDimensions02_m73817809 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.o
      _GA_Wrapper_configureAvailableCustomDimensions02_m1411017867 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.o
     (maybe you meant: _GA_Wrapper_configureAvailableCustomDimensions02_m1411017867)
  "_setCustomDimension03", referenced from:
      _GA_Setup_SetCustomDimension03_m1810616882 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.o
      _GA_Wrapper_SetCustomDimension03_m1476093010 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.o
      _GameAnalytics_SetCustomDimension03_m1712347313 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.o
      _GA_Wrapper_setCustomDimension03_m1290668082 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.o
     (maybe you meant: _GA_Wrapper_setCustomDimension03_m1290668082)
  "_configureAvailableCustomDimensions01", referenced from:
      _GA_Setup_SetAvailableCustomDimensions01_m1304166770 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.o
      _GA_Wrapper_SetAvailableCustomDimensions01_m2017262576 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.o
      _GA_Wrapper_configureAvailableCustomDimensions01_m25682024 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.o
     (maybe you meant: _GA_Wrapper_configureAvailableCustomDimensions01_m25682024)
  "_gameAnalyticsStartSession", referenced from:
      _GA_Wrapper_StartSession_m2220507432 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.o
      _GA_Wrapper_gameAnalyticsStartSession_m856198564 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.o
     (maybe you meant: _GA_Wrapper_gameAnalyticsStartSession_m856198564)
  "_setCustomDimension02", referenced from:
      _GA_Setup_SetCustomDimension02_m4195789303 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.o
      _GA_Wrapper_SetCustomDimension02_m1987306931 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.o
      _GameAnalytics_SetCustomDimension02_m1105036780 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.o
      _GA_Wrapper_setCustomDimension02_m1801882003 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.o
     (maybe you meant: _GA_Wrapper_setCustomDimension02_m1801882003)
  "_setCustomDimension01", referenced from:
      _GA_Setup_SetCustomDimension01_m2037569468 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.o
      _GA_Wrapper_SetCustomDimension01_m2143013396 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.o
      _GameAnalytics_SetCustomDimension01_m1748459067 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.o
      _GA_Wrapper_setCustomDimension01_m1957588468 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.o
     (maybe you meant: _GA_Wrapper_setCustomDimension01_m1957588468)
  "_showAlertMessage", referenced from:
      _NativeShare_showAlertMessage_m775874987 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
     (maybe you meant: _NativeShare_showAlertMessage_m775874987)
  "_initialize", referenced from:
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: @Omer Mujtaba did u get solution for this??

Comment: @shankarkn no I never.